# Odd CSS float and clear bug?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a odd problem while working on a small site.

I can't get my wrapper to wrap around all of my other divs correctly. My code looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="text">
            <form></form>
        </div>
        <div id="contact"><img />
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
            </map>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#header {
    height: 560px;
    width: 1190px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-image: url(../images/Header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#menu {
    width: 640px;
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    top: 115px;
}
#content {
    width: 1190px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
#text {
    width: 550px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
}
#contact {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 230px;
    top: 50px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

The wrapper seem to wrap on some of my pages but not all, and if I specify the size of the image in #contact it will fail on the other pages aswell. However, it does wrap the #text div.

Am greatly pleased for any help!

Best Regards
Robert

Comment: You also want to add an &nbsp; to the clear div so it doesn't collapse in certain browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The `position: relative;` style attached to the contact div is messing up the wrapper near the bottom. If you remove that style and then switch out the offsets to be margins instead, the wrapper div now wraps correctly across all the content divs. I have set up an example with your code here:
http://jsbin.com/eqecev/2/edit#preview

Comment: Hi,

Neither this did work, altho as I just stated above I managed to solve the issue by using margin-top: 50px; instead of just top: 50px;

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto;` to your wrapper div's CSS.

Comment: Sadly, this did not help. Altho I managed to solve the issue by using a margin-top: 50px; to the contact div instead of just top: 50px;.

Thank you anyway.